# How/where to store oauth (access/refresh) tokens on the identification server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

This has stumped me a bit, as in the oauth2 flow access tokens kind of important, describing what a "person" is allowed to do is and hence connect to sensitive info. Typically a client connects to a  backend server and sends their access token, this then gets forwarded to the oauth authorization server to verify.

However at the verification step things get a bit complicated.

To verify an access token it's obviously necessary that the token is also kept "somewhere"  in "some form" on the authorization server.

The "somewhere" has been solved to store it in some database. We use a static database, instead of an in memory one as the whole application (authorization server) needs to be able to quickly update the software and the sessions shouldn't be lost on these almost bidaily updates.

This however meant that we "store sensitive information on the server". Which I've read on security stackexchange should hence then be always hashed, so the original cannot be found. Thus we implementend bcrypt for this.

However this left us in an impossible situation:

A request comes in with a "possible" access token.
Normally the database would be checked to see if that access token exists and the rights that are given to that token
Instead with bcrypt we need to retrieve the whole list of tokens. And then compare (very very very slow) each of the stored tokens against the given access token.

The last step wouldn't be a problem if there would be like a dozen tokens, but this should obviously scalable up to thousands. Which makes it feel like the bcrypt hashing cannot be the solution.

Comment: _"Instead with bcrypt we need to retrieve the whole list of tokens. And then compare (very very very slow) each of the stored tokens against the given access token."_ - I can't follow you here, not at all. Which part of the whole process are you talking about here now, _exactly_? You were worried about storage of tokens on the auth server. So where is the problem now with sending the token to the auth server, hashing it there, and then go check the database for a record that matches that hash? That can hardly take forever, with the hash column in the database properly indexed.

Comment: @CBroe as bcrypt/encryption also adds salts (which the bcrypt calls one operation that is not divisible) you cannot do a direct compare even if you know the original: hashing twice will result in different hashes which cannot be compared easily. Bcrypt implemented its own "compare" function for that purpose, but that's (by design) slow

Comment: Guess only specifying the salt upfront, instead of letting bcrypt generate one on its own, would be a suitable option here then, I suppose. (If you send anything else besides the token, a username for example, the salt could be a static hash of that, so that you don't use the same static salt for everything.)

Answer (score -5):

```py
import bcrypt
import hashlib

# Example function to calculate token identifier
def calculate_token_identifier(token):
    hashed_token = hashlib.sha256(token.encode()).hexdigest()
    return hashed_token

# Example function to verify access token
def verify_access_token(database, incoming_token):
    token_identifier = calculate_token_identifier(incoming_token)
    potential_matches = database.search_by_token_identifier(token_identifier)

    for stored_token in potential_matches:
        if bcrypt.checkpw(incoming_token.encode(), stored_token['hashed_token']):
            return True

    return False

# Example usage
database = YourDatabase()  # Replace with your actual database implementation

access_token = "example_token"
is_valid_token = verify_access_token(database, access_token)
if is_valid_token:
    print("Access token is valid.")
else:
    print("Access token is invalid.")
```

Comment: uhh this is python code, and runs into the exact problem i have.